# What are the ASM options for hardware-monitoring for ARM devices?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, monitoring

I'm having trouble identifying what could possibly be a good instruction set that is granted to work on ARMv5 SoC and above, I'm also having some issues with the syntax since I'm used to a much simpler gcc asm syntax for X86 and the ARM one looks more complicated, but this is another topic ... I guess.

What I need to do is to check the feature of the SoC, like the frequency, the temperatures and the main features for computation purposes like Thumb or NEON support.

I know that ARM basically just designs and sells the blueprints for the CPU and the companies that buy the license are free to move bits around and make modifications, but I don't think that things are that bad in terms of entropy in the ARM world, or at least this kind of registers ( hardware monitoring and security features like the temperature ) are usually quite standard across the board, at least this is true in the X86 world where some CPUID instructions are probably complex, but you can check the main features of your CPU quite easily and most importantly you can code an application that works on both Intel and AMD with about the same code base.

What is a good set of register for this and if I pick 1 given register there are implication of the ASM syntax that I should use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arm is simpler than x86, give it some time with an open mind and you will see that.

Intel uses different foundries and design teams and technologies so there is no consistency either with temperature at least every other family is a different design team and they often change technologies/size every year or two.

Most of the arm cores provide on the minimal side registers that tell you everything from what processor core it is, what version on up to tons of registers describing which instructions are supported or not.

Your arm is going to run colder and/or faster than an x86 if you could apples to apples.

Unless something has changed if you want to put ARM's name on your chip or associate with your chip you cant go in and muck with the logic.  If you look in the TRM for a particular architecture you will see the strap options available.  Boot from 0x00000000 or 0xFFFF0000, start big or little endian, etc.

All arm cores from armv4t (ARM7TDMI) to the present support thumb, it is the only universal ARM instruction set.  One length neon and such are available in some of the cortex-m cores (cortex-m4) as well as different levels of support for thumb2 extensions.  As well as low power consumption, mips to watts while keeping mips to mhz.  The cortex-ms are microcontrollers so they will have options to turn items off or not turn them on to help conserve power.  but you can also implement that yourself on your on chip peripherals.

The cortex-m's wont give you ARM instructions, only thumb with thumb2 extensions.  All of the TRMs (Technical Reference Manuals) for the various arm cores are available at arms website (infocenter.arm.com) which will describe the features, strap options, axi/amba choices or sizes, etc.

Mips is your other primary choice for an soc core, I dont think your mips to watts will be as good.  You can of course go with an open core as well the openrisc or altor or mpx or amber or others that are there, but it is all on you for performance, temperature, etc.  (and floating point).

Not sure what you mean by hardware monitoring, but you have jtag and other typical debug options available.  If it is temperature you are after you have to work with your cell library provider and see what is available for the target foundry/process and then implement that peripheral and connect it to the arm. or outside world or both.

Bottom line you need to do more research, the info you need is available from arm for free or at the cost of an email address.

Comment: I need to do more research for sure, but, I can't test every possible ARM device, so I'm asking what is lowest common denominator across the board; with "monitoring" I mean getting CPU name, the temperatures, numbers of core, endianess, this kind of informations.

Comment: temperature is not a function of arm it is a function of the foundry, arm nor mips, etc have anything to do with it, it is the chip vendor and foundry and cell library.  cpu name, all of them.  Number of cores, well you are needing the mpcore or the cortex-A series to get a multicore.  arm is little endian with two different flavors of big endian but it is always best to stick with the native endianess no matter what processor so little endian.  (endianess matters very little these days).

Comment: are you in the semiconductor business are you building your own chip or are you buying one?  If you are buying one and mentioning multi-core then look at the ti omaps, cavium, marvell, nvidia, etc (I believe all have multi-core arm products).

Comment: ok, so I imagine that the only real "function" that I can expect from ARM is a vendor ID or a SoC ID or something like that, I suppose that I are offering this kind of feature to let the programmer detect the vendor at runtime. And no, I'm not buying or selling, I'm just a programmer and I need to detect features at runtime to be able to load the appropriate library, kinda like SSE support on X86 so you can use an SSE based library, I would like to do the same for ARM plus some extra info about the name of the brand and the SoC model.

Comment: the newer the arm the more info is available to determine exactly what libraries you can or cant use, quite a bit of information, much much more than a simple id and rev.  there are considerably more arms than x86s so it is a considerably larger task if you want to find vendor ids and some vendors may not have an id.  If you start with just arm cores and revs, then it is a smaller and manageable task.

Comment: yes, my point was, with what register should I start to get at least the right name/ID/vendor so then I can refer to the right documentation from the right vendor to extract the real useful information.

Comment: Are you using an arm processor right now?  If so what vendor and part id is it?  Or board and board name or rev or whatever, the board docs will tell you then chip the chip docs will tell you the arm core name and then you get the TRM from ARM and go from there.  Likewise you get the chip docs from the chip vendor and see if they have an identification register.  or take the path of looking through linux or other sources to see where they grab identification from.

Comment: my point is to write an application to put in the wild, not writing an application just for my arm device

Comment: my point is if you start with one particular one you will quickly see where to find this information and that it is quite likely that arm puts its info in the same or similar place from core to core.